# How do I get an auto-attached Elastic Network Interface from AWS Glue to detach from subnets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am setting up some AWS Glue jobs and wanted to switch the subnet that the connection was using. However, when I delete the connection the ENI from Glue is still attached to the subnet and I can't detach it (permission denied). Also when using "RDS" as the connection type, it defaults to using that subnet. If I create a JDBC connection I can force it to be the other subnet, but the ENI then is attached to both.

1. How do I get rid of this ENI? Deleting the connection didn't help
2. How do I control the auto-population of the subnet when setting up an RDS connection?